# What does "so since" mean here?

Tags: meaning

What does "since" refer to? Please consider grammar to tell me the meaning of "so since" in the following sentence:

> **This has been *so since* ancient times**, partly due to the geology of the area.

Comment: it looks more like "this has been so, since ancient times, partly due to the geology of the area".

Comment: *so = there* here!

Comment: so it was Author's mistake.

Comment: in this context, it's equivalent to the German word **so**, meaning **like this**.

Comment: It might help to note that ***So** this has been since ancient times* and *Since ancient times this has been **so*** are both valid perfectly reorderings of the cited text. That's to say, *syntactically*, ***so*** and ***since*** have no connection, and they can easily be separated with no change in meaning. I'd also say that including an extra comma after ***so*** above would be a *downgrade*, not an improvement.

Comment: @Alireza - No, it's not a mistake.  You're parsing it slightly incorrectly: it's not "so since", it's "this has been so" / "since ancient times".  *So*, as JavaLatte points out, essentially means "this way" or "like this".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"This has been so - since ancient times"

meaning This has been this way since ancient times. "so since" don't belong together.